# Are there any pairs of numbers (a,b) such that $a^a=b$ and $b^b=a$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

There is the trivial solution if we allow a=b=1.  Are there any nontrivial solutions where $a\ne b$?  The question is a "challenge" question from Tanton's Arithmetic and I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Also $a=b=-1$ is another answer.

Comment: I'm grateful to everyone for the responses and explanation -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\left(a^a\right)^{a^a}=a,$$ which for $a>0$ and $a\neq1$ gives
$$a^{a^{a+1}}=a$$ or
$$a^{a+1}=1$$ or
$$a+1=0,$$ which is impossible.

Comment: I have heard -1 is a number :)

Comment: @Zarrax The domain of the expression $a^a$ is $(0,+\infty).$

Comment: $x^{-1}$ is often considered to be defined when $x < 0$ but I see what you are saying. I guess it's a matter of which definition you prefer.

Comment: @Zarrax The domain of $x^{-1}$ it's $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, but the domain of $x^x$ it's $(0,+\infty).$

Comment: Since they are asking just for "solutions" it's not well-defined what is being allowed here.

Comment: @Zarrax I think it's clear. Unless otherwise stated, we work in $\mathbb R^2$ In $\mathbb Z^2$ there is also $(-1,-1),$ but it's not so in our case.

Comment: Not really... they could be allowing complex numbers for example, or any integers. The problem should specify the domain so as to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Zarrax Unless otherwise stated, we work in $\mathbb R$. For example, in the following problem: draw a graph of the function: $f(x)=x^x$ we don't say about complex numbers or integer numbers, we know that we work in $(0,+\infty).$ The situation with the starting problem is the same.

Comment: When one is asked to draw a graph of $x^x$, then the reader is led to consider the domain as $(0, \infty)$. But there are no cues like graphs here to help us make this determinations. It is just an ambiguity... the question should make the domain clear in my opinion.

Comment: @Zarrax I agree and not agree. I think it's better to work with an uniform language for which it's better, unless otherwise stated, to think that we work in $\mathbb R$. All these depends on a definition of course.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{ab}=(a^a)^b=b^b=a.$$
So either $a=1$ or $ab=1$. The second condition gives us $a^a=\frac{1}{a}$ implying $a=1$ or $a=-1$. Thus $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation leads to $b = a^{1 \over b}$, so since $b = a^a$ we have
$$a^{1 \over b} = a^a$$
Thus $a = {1 \over b}$. Then $b^b = a$ leads to $b^b = b^{-1}$, which in turn implies $b^{b+1} = 1$. Thus either $b = 1$ or $b = -1$. Thus we have either $(a,b) = (1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$, both of which can be directly plugged in and seen to solve the equations. (I am assuming $x^{-1}$ is given the appropriate definition for $x < 0$).

Answer (score 0):

$$ a ln(a) = ln(b)$$
$$ b ln(b) = ln(a)$$
substituting $ln(a) = \frac{ln(b)}{a}:

$$ b ln(b) = ln(a) = \frac{ln(b)}{a}$$
$$b = \frac{1}{a}$$

WLOG, we can assume $a \ge 1$, and $b \le 1$. However, $a^a = b$ doesn't make sense in the case where $a>1$. The reason why this $b = \frac{1}{a}$ despite none of the other values working is because we are multiplying by $ln(a) = 0$, which allows there to be extra solutions than the initial problem had.